# What are the differences between StateFlow and LiveData?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-flow, kotlin-stateflow

as I mentioned in the title, I'm curious about the general differences between the two. Can you help with this? I couldn't find the specific differences as there are complex examples on the internet.

1. What are the differences in terms of performance?
2. In which scenarios does it provide advantages?
3. Using StateFlow with Kotlin Flow is advantageous. But what is the risk of not switching to StateFlow in a project using LiveData?
4. Is Google deprecating LiveData? :)

Comment: 1. Negligible. 2. StateFlow enforces there being an initial value (but you could subclass MutableLiveData to do the same thing), so the value is never null if the type is not nullable. 3. I don't understand the question. How can you use a Flow in a project that doesn't use Flow? 4. Don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: 4. Is Google deprecating LiveData?

Comment: There is no public announcement that they plan to deprecate it. StateFlow cannot practically be used in Java, so I doubt it will be deprecated any time in the next few years.

Comment: 3. Using StateFlow with Kotlin Flow is advantageous. But what is the risk of not switching to StateFlow in a project using LiveData?

Comment: Regarding 2, I also think Flows operators are a lot easier to use than LiveData's transformations. 3. I still don't understand what you're saying about using StateFlow with Flow. StateFlow is just a subtype of Flow. It's kind of like saying it's advantageous to use Comparable in a project that has Ints. There's no risk to not switching, unless you're afraid LiveData might get deprecated soon.

Comment: I am satisfied with your answers. Thank you. 3. Sorry for not explaining the question fully.

Answer (score 18):

I just switched to `StateFlow`, so this is a great time for me to answer your question.

---

> What are the differences in terms of performance?

Honestly, I don't know, but since it's pushed by **Kotlin** and **Android**, just trust them :).

---

> In which scenarios does it provide advantages?

1. For `LiveData` you are not forced to give an initial value, it may end up writing more code in `init{}`; But for `StateFlow` you are **Forced** to give an initial value (including `null`), it may save your code a bit.
2. For `LiveData` even if you give an initial value, you still need to do **Null Check**  when you access its `value` (see [this](https://youtu.be/JnN6EFZ6DO8?t=125)), it's kind of annoying. But that's not gonna happen on `StateFlow` - it will be what it should be.
3. For `LiveData` you cannot easily, or elegantly observe data changes **JUST** inside `ViewModel`, you are gona use `observeForever()` which is also mentioned in [here](https://youtu.be/JnN6EFZ6DO8?t=215). But for `StateFlow` it's easy, do it like following:

   ```
    class FirstViewModel() : ViewModel() {
        val uiScope = viewModelScope

        val name = MutableStateFlow("Sam")      //must have initial value
        //val name = MutableStateFlow<String?>(null)   //null is acceptable

        init {
            observeName()
        }

        private fun observeName() = uiScope.launch {    //must run in coroutine scope                                                       
            name.collect { name ->                      //for Fragment / Activity, use lifecycleScope.launch{}
                //do your stuff
            }
        }
    }
   ```

---

> Using StateFlow with Kotlin Flow is advantageous. But what is the risk of not switching to StateFlow in a project using LiveData?

What is the risk of not switching to **Kotlin** in a project using **Java**? :)

---

> Is Google deprecating LiveData?

I would say yes, and they would say no, no for "not yet to say it loudly" :).

Comment: Amazing explanation!

Comment: But wouldn't the `//do your stuff` block involve updating the UI? How can this be done in viewmodel without either passing the view to the viewmodel (violating MVVM) or using another observable/callback (in which case, what's the point of having `StateFlow` at all?)

Comment: @Matt Observing `StateFlow/LiveData` doesn''t mean that work is UI-related, I may want to update an variable based on the changes of another `StateFlow/LiveData`, but I don't want that variable to be exposed to the `Fragment/Activity`.

Comment: @SamChen That sounds like an unusual use case, and all of Google's examples in the documentation have `StateFlow` updating a UI directly. I don't see the purpose of `StateFlow`. It sounds like it's the same as `LiveData` except now you have to handle your coroutines in the Activity/Fragment (which google itself claims is bad practice).

Comment: @Matt This video may help: https://youtu.be/JnN6EFZ6DO8.

Comment: @SamChen I finally got a chance to watch the video and still do not understand the benefit of `StateFlow`. The only real argument he gives for it is that now you can pass the fragment as a lifecycle owner rather than `viewLifecycleOwner`. I think this is yet another Android fad that has no benefit.