# LiveData Vs StateFlow: Should we switch from Live data to State Flow?

Tags: android, android-livedata, kotlin-flow, android-studio-arctic-fox, kotlin-stateflow

I have come across articles that recommend switching to StateFlow.
Like the one [here](https://medium.com/swlh/migrating-from-livedata-to-stateflow-4f28d6889a04).
Also in the new Android studio, StateFlow support is automatically included in the functionality of data binding, including the coroutines dependencies.
Live data is already in use in most of the apps.
Should we migrate from LiveData to StateFlow? What are the benefits?

[image]

Comment: You can check out my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68635436/what-are-the-differences-between-stateflow-and-livedata/68775562#68775562

Answer (score 33):

There is not much difference between State Flow and Live Data. The Main difference come in that State Flow requires an Initial value hence no need to check for nullability. The Second Difference come in unregistering the consumer; Live Data does this automatically when the view goes to STOPPED state while State Flow does not. To achieve similar behaviour as Live Data, you can collect the flow in a `Lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle` block.

**Benefits of State Flow**

- State flow is included in coroutines library and can be used in Multiplatform Projects
- Using one API in your project(Flow), not two (LiveData and Flow).
- It's Kotlin, Why Not

Comment: For stopping the `flow` when the screen is not visible,  you can use `lifecycleScope.launchWhenStarted {  }`.

Comment: @SamChen the problem with `lifecyclescope.launchWhenStarted { }`  is that it suspend the coroutine and no more data can be collected from the UI when the lifecycle is STOPPED but the producer still processed data. Cancellation of the flow only happens after the view is DESTROYED. With Lifecycle.repeatOnLifecycle you specify a Lifecycle State as a parameter, and each time the state is met, a new coroutine is called and when the state lifecycle falls below the specifies State, it is cancelled. https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/a-safer-way-to-collect-flows-from-android-uis-23080b1f8bda

Comment: Very good point, thanks, I learned a lot!

Comment: And it has no dependencies with the android framework (unlike LiveData), which allows to avoid android in our view models

Comment: @Yago yes, a very good point.

Comment: I don't believe this mimics the LiveData behaviour. With LiveData, if an item is emitted while the screen is not visible (say the user backgrounded the app), when the user reopens the screen they will have the data delivered as expected (ie, LiveData actually holds on to the item until the Activity/Fragment is back on a state where it can deliver that data). With this "repeatOnLifecycle" approach,  the data would be lost instead in that case.

Answer (score 10):

It depends on what you want,

If you want a manual, full and versatile control over the app , go for state flow

If you want a partially automatic or relatively easy-to-use method for your app , I will say - stick with live data

In case If you want to know my personal opinion, it's state flow,  as i prefer control over easy-to-use. I don't mind writing a few extra lines for it as it can be useful for me sometimes.

Think of it like using a soda opener for soda and using a nail cutter
I can do it with both but the soda opener Is easy to use in this case but , don't have much versatility like nail cutter.

And at the end of the day , I use state flow everytime because, I am lazy to learn live data for some projects as state flow can do what live data can even though live data will be much easier.

And you should decide what you want to choose and if you're not as lazy as me , I recommend go with both and use the one which is suitable each time.

Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

**Flow is the best practice**

Livedata is used to observe data without having any hazel to handle lifecycle problems. Whereas Kotlin flow is used for continuous data integration and it also simplified the asynchronous programming.

Take Room Library as an example. First, it used livedata to transmit data from the database to UI. It solved most of the existing problems. But when there are any future changes in the database livedata is helpless in this situation.

After a while, the room used Kotlin flow to solve this problem. With Flow as return-type, room created a new possibility of seamless data integration across the app between database and UI without writing any extra code

read [this](https://medium.com/swlh/migrating-from-livedata-to-stateflow-4f28d6889a04) article on medium website

Comment: (Livedata is helpless in this situation)  I think its not true, when the room database is updated LiveData can also send an update without needing to poll the data from Room

Comment: @muralikurapati Is it possible though to make LiveData to have only the latest value (conflated ) , so that if multiple calls are done to change the value, only the latest one will be used ? If in the background thread I call multiple times to "postValue", yet the UI thread is still running during this time, wouldn't it get multiple observations values for each time of postValue ?

Answer (score 1):

In Android, LiveData and State are two classes that can be used to hold and observe data in your app. Both classes are part of the Android Architecture Components library, which is a set of libraries for building robust, testable, and maintainable apps.

LiveData is a data holder that is lifecycle-aware, meaning it only delivers updates to observers that are in an active state. It is useful for holding data that needs to be observed and updated in the UI, such as data from a network request or a database query.

State is a data holder that represents an immutable state value that can be observed. It is useful for holding data that does not change often, or data that should not be modified directly.

Which of these classes is "best" to use depends on your specific needs and requirements. Here are a few factors to consider when deciding between LiveData and State:

**Mutability:** LiveData is mutable, meaning its value can be changed, while State is immutable, meaning its value cannot be changed directly.
**Lifecycle awareness:** LiveData is lifecycle-aware, while State is not.
**Transformation:** LiveData supports transformation through the use of the Transformations class, while State does not.
In general, if you need to hold and observe data that needs to be updated in the UI and you want the data to be lifecycle-aware, LiveData is a good choice. If you need to hold and observe data that is immutable or does not change often, State is a good choice.

It is also worth considering whether you need to transform or map the data being held and observed. If you do, LiveData is a better choice because it supports transformation through the Transformations class.

Comment: I am curious about the Mutability Point as there is also a Class called MutableStateFlow